# Como borrar caracteres en un "object" de un DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

tengo $ 48405,892 en una posicion del DataFrame y necesito quitar el signo "$" y cambiar la "," por un "."
Pero cuando intento quitar el "$" utilizo:

datos["Importe"].replace({'$':''}, regex=True, inplace = True)
(dentro de datos["Importe"] se encuentra este valor y varios mas, con el mismo signo)

y el resultado sigue siendo $ 48405,892 (con el espacio entre el símbolo "$" y el numero)

Si alguien me puede decir donde esta mi error
Agradeceré sus comentarios de antemano

Este es el Dataframe que se genero a partir de un CSV

```
     Proveedor    FechaOP        NumeroOP                TipoDoc   FechaDoc  \
0   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-14   
1   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-14   
2   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-14   
3   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-14   
4   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-14   
5   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-14   
6   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-15   
7   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-15   
8   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-15   
9   DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267                Factura 2021-07-16   
10  DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267  Anticipo de Proveedor 2021-07-19   
11  DIELO S.A. 2021-08-02  00001-00073267    Retención Ganancias 2021-08-02   
12  DIELO S.A. 2021-08-09  00001-00073372                Factura 2021-07-22   
13  DIELO S.A. 2021-08-09  00001-00073372                Factura 2021-07-22   
 

          NumeroDoc       Importe DemoraPago  
0   A00011-00079782  $ 448203,272    19 days  
1   A00011-00079791  $ 165391,218    19 days  
2   A00011-00079783  $ 115984,336    19 days  
3   A00011-00079790    $ 6583,416    19 days  
4   A00011-00079780  $ 111834,640    19 days  
5   A00011-00079781   $ 11598,431    19 days  
6   A00011-00079838   $ 46774,706    18 days  
7   A00011-00079840  $ 663493,229    18 days  
8   A00011-00079839   $ 84754,223    18 days  
9   A00011-00079867  $ 134771,855    17 days  
10   00001-00073144   -$ 2944,060    14 days  
11   00001-00014430   $ 23701,475     0 days  
12  A00011-00080057   $ 84213,906    18 days  
13  A00011-00080056   $ 25273,464    18 days
```

Comment: `datos["Importe"].apply(lambda x: x.replace({'$':''}, regex=True, inplace = True)`

Comment: Christian, gracias. Spyder me tira este error cuando pruebo tu codigo: TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Pues es por que replace solo acepta 2 parámetros que sería el string a reemplazar y el carácter por el que será reemplazado

Comment: correcto, pero me da error y no quita el simbolo "$". Gracias

Comment: ponlo así `datos["Importe"].apply(lambda x: x.replace('$',''))`

Comment: ahora NO da error, pero NO elimina el simbolo "$".

Comment: podrías colocar el DataFrame para poder hacer las pruebas??

Comment: Bueno a mí si me elimina el símbolo. Asegúrate de poner `df["Importe"] = df["Importe"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("$",""))`

Comment: Christian muchas gracias! solucionado!

Comment: @Christian tu último comentario para mí es una respuesta válida y que debería ser puesto como respuesta.

Comment: @Esei listo la he añadido y complementado un poco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal es que no estas haciendo la asignación a la columna, al hacer `datos["Importe"].replace({'$':''}, regex=True, inplace = True)` simplemente se hace la operación y devuelve un resultado mas no es aplicado directamente al DataFrame, si hubieras hecho `datos["Importe"] = datos["Importe"].replace({'$':''}, regex=True, inplace = True)` tu pregunta habría sido totalmente diferente ya que te devolvería `None` en todas las filas :)

Lo que puedes hacer es recorrer cada fila de la columna `Importe` usando el método `apply()` y pasarle una función `lambda` que será la encargada de reemplazar el caracter. De igual forma nos aseguramos de que el resultado de la operación sea puesto en la columna `Importe`

```py
datos["Importe"] = datos["Importe"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("$",""))
```